# JavaScript regex: Positive lookbehind alternative (for Safari and other browsers that do not support lookbehinds)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for an alternative for this:

```
(?<=\.\d\d)\d
```

(Match third digit after a period.)

I'm aware I can solve it by using other methods, but I have to use a regular expression and more importantly I have to use replace on the string, without adding a callback.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turn the lookbehind in a consuming pattern and use a *capturing* group:

And use it as shown below:

```js
var s = "some string.005";
var rx = /\.\d\d(\d)/;
var m = s.match(/\.\d\d(\d)/);
if (m) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Or, to get all matches:

```js
const s = "some string.005 some string.006";
const rx = /\.\d\d(\d)/g;
let result = [], m;
while (m = rx.exec(s)) {
  result.push(m[1]);
}
console.log( result );
```

An example with `matchAll`:

```js
const result = Array.from(s.matchAll(rx), x=>x[1]);
```

EDIT:

To remove the `3` from the `str.123` using your current specifications, use the same *capturing* approach: capture what you need and restore the captured text in the result using the `$n` backreference(s) in the replacement pattern, and just match what you need to remove.

```js
var s = "str.123";
var rx = /(\.\d\d)\d/; 
var res = s.replace(rx, "$1");
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Unfortunatley I can't use match, like I said I have to use replace without a call back, so using a capturing group is not applicable.

Comment: Well, I understand. Then, still, the same approach can be used: match what you do not need and match and capture what you need. Try `var res  = s.replace(/^.*\.\d\d(\d).*/, "$1")`.

Comment: The expected behavior is `var s = "str.123"` `s.replace(/(?<=\.\d\d)\d/, '');` `// S is now "str.12"` Apologies for not being more clear about that.

Comment: Ok, you have `str.123` value. Are you trying to get `3` with `replace`? My update actually returns `3` for `str.123` input.

Comment: No, `3` should be removed from the string by `replace`.

Comment: Ok, great, see my updated code. Same approach, use ***capturing***.